# Coefficients returned from CoefficientRules

Tags: polynomials

When I used an older version of Mathematica, CoefficientRules returned coefficients as entered, say x^2 +2x  -4 y + 13., it returned {{2,0}->1,{1,0}->2,{0,1}->-4,{0,0}->13.} with all coefficients returned as integers except the last one.

I used this to identify non-valid (== non-integral) coefficients in my polynomial.

In version 13 of Mathematica, if I enter one coefficient as non-integral all other integer
coefficients are returned as non-inetrgral as well.

I real want to have all coefficients in my polynomials returned as given.

Any suggestions?

Kent

Comment: `CoefficientRules[poly // Rationalize]`

Comment: @BobHanlon:  I think the OP wants the coefficients to be returned as given, not all rationalized.  In other words, the desired output is `{2, 0} -> 1, {1, 0} -> 2, {0, 1} -> -4, {0, 0} -> 13.}`.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - Then `ReplacePart[CoefficientRules[poly // Rationalize], -1 -> ({0, 0} -> (poly /. Thread[Variables[poly] -> 0]))]`

Comment: @BobHanlon:  That doesn't look like it will work if any term other than the constant term is non-rational.  But admittedly the OP only gave us the one use case.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to work, though the indexing is off by one compared to `CoefficientRules`:

```
expr = x^2 + 2 x - 4 y + 13.
result = Most[ArrayRules[CoefficientList[expr, {x, y}]]]
(* {{1, 1} -> 13., {1, 2} -> -4, {2, 1} -> 2, {3, 1} -> 1} *)
```

To regain the original indexing, you can apply the following command:

```
MapAt[# - 1 &, result, {All, 1}] 
(* {{0, 0} -> 13., {0, 1} -> -4, {1, 0} -> 2, {2, 0} -> 1} *)
```

The ordering of the results is also different;  judicious application of `SortBy` can probably fix this if needed.

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

```
CoefficientRules[
  x^2 + 2 x - 4 y + 13. /. x_Real | x_Complex :> \[FormalA][x],
  {x, y}] /. \[FormalA][x_] :> x

(*  {{2, 0} -> 1, {1, 0} -> 2, {0, 1} -> -4, {0, 0} -> 13.}  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function which should reproduce your desired results for any polynomial.

```
coefficientRulesAlt[polynomial_] :=
 Module[{
   var, pows, lis,
   poly = polynomial},
  var = Variables[poly];
  pows = Table[{var[[i]], #[[i]]}, {i, Length[var]}] & /@ 
    Tuples[Table[ix, {ix, 0, #}] & /@ Exponent[poly, var]];
  lis = Table[
    Table[Last@pows[[j]][[i]], {i, Length[pows[[j]]]}] -> 
     Fold[Coefficient[#1, #2[[1]], #2[[2]]] &, poly, pows[[j]]], {j, 
     Length[pows]}];
  Reverse[If[Last[#] != 0, #, Nothing] & /@ lis]]
```

Input

```
coefficientRulesAlt[13. + 2 x + x^2 - 4 y]
```

Output

```
{{2, 0} -> 1, {1, 0} -> 2, {0, 1} -> -4, {0, 0} -> 13.}
```

Input

```
coefficientRulesAlt[126.357 + 2.1354 z + π*x^20*z^2 - 4 y]
```

Output

```
{{1, 0, 0} -> -4, {0, 2, 20} -> π, {0, 1, 0} -> 
  2.1354, {0, 0, 0} -> 126.357}
```

Comment: Great, this solves my problem for my coefficient check for my polynomials!

Comment: It seems that the behaviour of CoeffcientRules  changed sometime between version 10 and 13 of Mathematica. Why it was changed is unclear to me. Anybody?